# How to add a bcc using golang standard `net/smtp`?

Tags: go

I am trying to add a list of bcc using go's net/smtp package.

```
    to := []string{"recpt@gmail.com"}
    msg := []byte("To: recpt@gmail.com\r\n" +
                  "cc: cc@gmail.com\r\n" +
                  "bcc: bcc@gmail.com\r\n" +
                  "Subject: TEST SUBJECT\r\n" +
                  "\r\n" +
                  "Test Email Body")
    err := smtp.SendMail("mailserver.com:25", auth, "sender@gmail.com", to, msg)
```

the bcc part doesn't work.

P.S. I don't want to use any external lib.

Comment: From the docs: "The msg parameter should be an RFC 822-style email with headers first, a blank line, and then the message body. The lines of msg should be CRLF terminated. The msg headers should usually include fields such as "From", "To", "Subject", and "Cc". Sending "Bcc" messages is accomplished by including an email address in the to parameter but not including it in the msg headers."

Comment: Thanks, I am able to figure out the bcc for my send email code